# How to set Burn UI dependent on a util:RegistrySearch

Tags: wix, burn

We have a requirement that when a user installs multiple products they should all get installed in the same folder.

We use a util:RegistrySearch to find the correct path. If this value is set, we want to disable the inputbox for location in the options pane. We also want to display the path in the inputbox.

The MSI properties will be set correctly, but it will not show in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can propagate the value to the BootstrapperApplication and use it in the UI.
For example, if this is the RegistrySearch Element:

```
<util:RegistrySearch
      Id="NetFrameworkRegistrySearch"
      Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
      Result="value"
      Root="HKLM"
      Value="Release"
      Variable="NetFrameworkRegistryValue" />
```

you can propagate this resulting variable "NetFrameworkRegistryValue" to the bundle, and consume it by accessing the BootstrapperApplication.Engine properties.
For example in C# using engine.StringVariables["NetFrameworkRegistryValue"]